# UIScrollView: View does not scroll automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm new at Swift/iOS and I'm making a simple app to keep track of the medicine cabinet I have at home. I'm having trouble managing the on screen keyboard for text input.

The app is basically a table view with the data entries, and when pressing one of them you go into a detail view with some details.

In this detail view I have a UIScrollView, which is constrained to be equal to the Safe Area, inside it a UIView named "Container View" which is the same size as the Scrollview, and inside that one further views to compose the screen using AutoLayout (with no warnings).

Inside one of those child views there is a UITextField which I use to gather notes typed in by the user via the on screen keyboard.

I added some code to manage the onscreen keyboard, adjusting the view bottom inset when it shows up to prevent the keyboard from hiding the text field, and removing that inset when the keyboard disappears.

I ended up with the following code, which I got from hackingwithswift.com (and the property observers set up to call this function properly, which I have confirmed to be working):

```
func adjustInsetForKeyboardShowHide(notification: Notification) {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }

    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset

}
```

However even though the function is correctly called when the keyboard comes on screen the view doesn't scroll. I'm not sure if the problem lies here or somewhere in IB...

What strikes me is that i can scroll down manually after the keyboard comes on screen, to the right amount, it just doesn't do so automatically as I'd like it to. As expected the view does not scroll when the onscreen keyboard is not displayed, so apparently the adjust function works fine, it just does not scroll on its own.

When the keyboard disappears the view readjusts to normal again, so that part is working fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scrollView you have to set the content offset. So in your case you will have to do it like this:

```
if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: keyboardViewEndFrame.size.height), animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! With that replacement the view does move, but too far up. I'm now trying to troubleshoot why!

Comment: Sorry. You have to use the height. I just edited my answer.

Comment: I figured it out! The behaviour I wanted is obtained by setting keyboardViewEndFrame.height instead of minY. Thanks a lot for your help, it was the scroll command I could not figure out and you gave it to me!